# how to limit oauth login attemps in laravel?

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, login-attempts

In several cases, I limit login attempts in laravel project but I can't find any solution in oauth login. Specifically, my question is how do I limit login attempts using this api "/v1/oauth/token" or any custom method.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiting from Laravel it's the best way to solve your issue. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/rate-limiting

Comment: Well it is good way to limit it. But I have send an axios request to laravel backend which is by default passport client api "/v1/oauth/token". Should I use custom authentication method or is there any solution for passport oauth?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).